# Sharing object between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, object, sharing

In my program I like to create an object and then pass it to 2 different threads and 1 should update the values of the object and the other thread should use that values. But when the thread try to use the values I get the error that the object doesn't have any values. How can I resolve this problem?

```
SS_list list = new SS_list();
Files_list lof = new Files_list();

CS_UDP udp =  new CS_UDP(cs_port, list, lof);
CD_TCP tcp = new CS_TCP(cs_port, list, lof);
```

SS_list stores a list of Storage server available;

Files_list stores a list of Files available in the storage server;

CS_UDP makes a communication in udp, and returns to the user a list of files available and the IP to a storage server;

CD_TCP makes a communication in tcp and actualizes the files in the Files_list

Comment: you can acheive it by using synchronization in threads.. Just go through multithreading..

Comment: Can you please update your code here? From just description how can we tell you where exactly you are making mistake.

Comment: you must use wait() and notify() method... to communicate between two threads..

Answer (score 0):

The basic of multi-threading:
If a tread has a object it will "lock" that object, putting data in the object or taking it out will not change anything unless the object is written back to the memory or disk.

In your code example there is no wait for the CS_UDP to finish writing to the list, therefor the list will still be empty when CD_TCP starts reading.

Hope this helps!